# What collection allows me to search by parameters on objects?

Tags: c#

I have a phone object as so:

```
public string grade { get; set; }
public string network { get; set; }
public decimal price { get; set; }
```

I have a loop where I parse raw data and on each pass I create a new phone object.  My task now is to define a collection to hold these phone objects.

I am not sure what sort of collection I need for them.  I need to be able to define `grade` and `network` in my code and get back the price easily so a generic list is out of the question (I think). Should I be using multidimensional array?

There will only ever be one phone per grade & network (this is all data for the same phone, just different prices depending on network or grade).

What is the easiest collection I can use to achieve the goal of feeding in `grade` and `network` and getting out price?

Comment: If you are going to store all three values together in an object, then it doesn't matter; just use `List`. If you put `grade` and `network` into an object, then a `Dictionary<Phone, decimal>` makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I think you're over-thinking this, a `List` seems fine

Comment: @BradleyDotNET don't forget to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` if you want keys to have value semantics, instead of referential one.

Comment: Consider doing some research on databases.  As your problem expands beyond the simple case you're proposing now, the best answer to your general question of the data structure to allow looking up values based on some 'key' or 'index' is to use a database.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Yes, that would be important for a `Dictionary` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a typed list. Define a class:

```
public class Phone
{
   public string grade { get; set; }
   public string network { get; set; }
   public decimal price { get; set; }
}
```

Then define a list:

```
var list = new List<Phone>();
```

EDIT:

Per requests, here's how to query it.

```
var price = list.Where(p => p.grade = "grade" && p.network == "network").Select(p => p.price).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It would help if you also showed an example of how he could access the price given the `grade` and `network`.

Comment: @Paul Thank you very much, this is how I have added it to my code.  A quick question, are the text paramenters case sensisitive?  If so, can that be turned off with an option somewhere?

Comment: They are as written above. To do a case insensitive compare, you do the following: if (phone.Grade.Equals("foo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) { }. OR the LINQ statement above would be: list.Where(p => p.grade.Equals("foo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).

Answer (score 1):

Any list will do if you use LINQ for querying.

```
List<Phone> list = ...


string grade = "...";
string network = "...";

var phone = list.FirstOrDefault(
   p => 
       p.grade == grade && 
       p.network == network );

if ( phone != null )
{
  // found one
  var price = phone.price;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overthinking this. A `List<Phone>` should work fine.

```
var phones = new List<Phone>();
```

Since you said there's only ever one price for each combination of `grade` and `network` you can use the LINQ method `Single`:

```
string network = string.Empty; //something useful here
string grade = string.Empty;
decimal price = phones.Single(p => p.network == network && p.grade == grade).price;
```

This will throw an error if there is more than one combination of the same `grade` and `network`.

Comment: `This will throw an error if there is more than one combination` or found none with this combination. Also notice, that phones is a `List<Phone>`, `Single` will return an entity of type `Phone` not `decimal`. You'll need to access price on that object.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov yes, if there is no combination of the `grade` and `network` this will throw an error. Use `SingleOrDefault` if it's possible that situation arises. Thanks for pointing out the return type of `Single`, I forgot the `.price`.